# Develop a Hello World plugin for Ollydbg

Tags: ollydbg, c, dll, plugin

I wanted to write a plugin for Ollydbg 2 which shows just a simple message. I write the following one but it doesn't load in ollydbg. I am using ollydbg 2 and my DLL can't load by it. Where is the problem?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "plugin.h"

#define PLUGINNAME      L"Hello World"      // Unique plugin name
#define VERSION         L"2.00.01"          // Plugin version
HINSTANCE               hDllInstance;       // Instance of plugin DLL
static t_table          HelloWorld;         // Hello World table


// Menu function of main menu, opens or brings to top list of bookmarks.
static int OpenHelloWorldMessage(int mode) {
    if (mode == MENU_VERIFY)
    {
        return MENU_NORMAL;
    }
    else if (mode == MENU_EXECUTE) 
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"This is a Sample Program.", L"Message", MB_OK);
        return MENU_NOREDRAW;
    }
    else
    {
        return MENU_ABSENT;
    }
};

// Menu function of main menu, displays About dialog.
static int ShowHelloWorldAbout(int arg_mode) {
    int dwNumber;
    wchar_t wcStringProgram[TEXTLEN];
    if (arg_mode == MENU_VERIFY)
        return MENU_NORMAL;

    else if (arg_mode == MENU_EXECUTE) {
        // Debuggee should continue execution while message box is displayed.
        Resumeallthreads();

        dwNumber = StrcopyW(wcStringProgram, TEXTLEN, L"Hello Plugin v");
        dwNumber += StrcopyW(wcStringProgram + dwNumber, TEXTLEN - dwNumber, VERSION);
        dwNumber += StrcopyW(wcStringProgram + dwNumber, TEXTLEN - dwNumber, L"\nCopyright (C) 2019-2020 lightning");
        StrcopyW(wcStringProgram + dwNumber, TEXTLEN - dwNumber, L"MSVC Compiler");
        MessageBox(hwollymain, wcStringProgram, L"Bookmark plugin", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

        Suspendallthreads();

        return MENU_NOREDRAW;
    };

    return MENU_ABSENT;
};

static t_menu HelloWorldMainMenu[] = {
    { L"Open Hello", L"Show Hello Message", K_NONE, OpenHelloWorldMessage, NULL, 0 },
    { L"|About", L"About Hello Plugin", K_NONE, ShowHelloWorldAbout, NULL, 0 },
    { NULL, NULL, K_NONE, NULL, NULL, 0 }
};


extc t_menu* __cdecl ODBG2_PluginMenu(wchar_t* type) {

    if (wcscmp(type, PWM_MAIN) == 0)
        return HelloWorldMainMenu;

    return NULL;
};

static t_menu HelloWorldMenu[] = {
    { L"|>STANDARD", L"", K_NONE, NULL, NULL, 0}
};

BOOL WINAPI DllEntryPoint(HINSTANCE hi, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved) {
    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
        hDllInstance = hi;          // Mark plugin instance
    return 1;                       // Report success
};

extc int __cdecl ODBG2_Pluginquery(int arg_olly_version, ulong* arg_features, wchar_t arg_plugin_name[SHORTNAME], wchar_t arg_plugin_version[SHORTNAME]) {
    if (arg_olly_version < 201)
        return 0;
                                                    // Report name and version to OllyDbg.
    wcscpy(arg_plugin_name, PLUGINNAME);            // Name of plugin
    wcscpy(arg_plugin_version, VERSION);            // Version of plugin
    return PLUGIN_VERSION;                          // Expected API version
};


extc int __cdecl ODBG2_Plugininit(void) 
{
    OpenHelloWorldMessage(MENU_EXECUTE);

    return 0;
};
```

I wanted when it gets load show a message but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to put that in `ODBG2_Plugininit` as suggested [here](http://www.ollydbg.de/Help/ODBG2_Plugininit.htm)?

Comment: I put the full source code, it shows message now but I wanted this message show when I click on plugin menu and select show message.